# Append a file to a ZipFile in python

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

First I created a new zipfile:

```
import zipfile
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('/data2/new.zip', mode='w')
```

then I wanted to append a file into the newly created zipfile, say `download.py` in another folder:

```
zf.write('/data2/another_folder/download.py')
```

All seemed fine until I unzip it locally and I found that it did not just append the file, but also append all the folders, `data2` and `another_folder`. I have to open `/data2/new/data2/another_folder/` to find `download.py`.

I want to append and only append the file to zipfile. How can I avoid the aforementioned situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zipfile.write()` method takes an optional `arcname` argument that specifies what the name of the file should be inside the zipfile.

```
import os
import zipfile


zf.write('/data2/another_folder/download.py', 'download.py')
zf.close()
```

Here's a function to zip multiple files together:

```
def zip(list_of_file_paths):
   zf = zipfile.ZipFile("Zipfile.zip", "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
   for path in list_of_file_paths:
       filename = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(path))
       zf.write(path, filename)
   zf.close()

zip(['path/to/file1', 'path/to/file2', ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it saved me lots of headache :)

Comment: @HelenNeely You're welcome! If you haven't already, do feel free to upvote. Thank ye.

Answer (score 1):

```
zf.write('path/to/file.txt', arcname='name_without_path.txt')
```

should solve that for you, if you want to keep the same name without the path you can also do this:

```
filepath = 'path/to/file.txt'
zf.write(filepath, arcname=os.path.basename(filepath))
```

that assumes you did `import os` of course